# How to use stderr with execve

Tags: c, stderr, execve

I want to see only `football` in the stdout. And if instead of using echo I use a nonexistant command, then Id like it to be redirected to stderr. Im doubting if its doable.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char *tab[] = {"echo", "football", "2> /dev/null", NULL};

        char test [strlen("echo") + strlen( "/bin/" ) +1];
        strcpy(test, "/bin/");
        strcat(test, "echo");
        execve(test, tab, NULL);
    
        return 0;
}
```

I get `football 2> /dev/null` but I want only to see `football`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, by why not `char test[] = "/bin/echo"`?

Comment: As for your problem, redirection is handled by the *shell*, not by the commands themselves. If you want redirection, you need to invoke a shell (e.g. `/bin/sh -c "echo football 2> /dev/null"`).

Comment: Alternatively to shell usage you can redirect the standard stream(s) yourself. Use these terms in your favorite web search engine.

Comment: You should use `execv()` rather than `execve()` unless you are going to provide a modified environment to the executed command.